# PHP printer setting for client's browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, barcode-printing

I have product base website  developed in PHP 'Codeignitor'. Now i want to print Barcode label from 'client browser' with my custom 'printer setings'. I am using Zebra 'GK420d' thermal printer. the code should be working in all browser. We are using code128 method to create barcode.

How can i set custom printer setting to client's printer.

In chrome 'browser' we can get default printer setting set in system but in 'firefox' we are not geting any kind of default setting, while printing we have to set dimension every time in 'Firefox'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? I would suggest taking a look at [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post enough details to make sure you get the answer you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. we can set printer setting for our own browser  but we need to set this setting to every client who use this website or when print barcode from our website. if we can not set setting then the print of barcode will not  be proper.